# Using GPU for tensorflow object detection

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, object-detection

I have trained a faster R-CNN model for object detection using TensorFlow object detection with Google colab. But when testing videos google colab crashes, that's why I decided to test on my pc and installed CUDA 10.0 and Cudnn 7.6.5 and TensorFlow-gpu = 1.15.
But the test is so so slow as if it is running on a CPU. I get this message when testing so I guess it is using my GPU (photo).

Does anyone know a solution to test a video in a faster way?
Is the problem with CUDA or my GPU?

Thank you[image: photo]

Comment: Can you run `tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')` please?

Comment: this command throws error since I am using tensorflow 1.15 , but running               `from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())` gives : [name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 5669582133996130572
, name: "/device:GPU:0"
device_type: "GPU"
memory_limit: 1457838491
locality {
  bus_id: 1
  links {
  }
}
incarnation: 8403467626327144411
physical_device_desc: "device: 0, name: GeForce MX110, pci bus id: 0000:02:00.0, compute capability: 5.0"
]

Comment: Sorry, didn't see you were on tensorflow 1.15. Could you try `tf.test.is_gpu_available`?

You're on an MX110, which isn't a particularly fast GPU - my suspicion is that it's working properly.

Comment: The GPU you are using is one of the slowest in the market, so do not expect something quick, specially since it also has little RAM.

Comment: and `print(tf.test.is_gpu_available())` gives True

Answer (score 1):

From Comments

> `tf.test.is_gpu_available()` tells whether Tensorflow can access a
> `GPU`.
>
> *[THIS FUNCTION](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/test/is_gpu_available) IS DEPRECATED. It will be removed in a future version. Instructions for updating: Use
> `tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')` instead*
>
> If it returns `True`, then there is no issue in using GPU. But
> `GeForce MX110` is slowest since it also has little RAM. For better
> performance you can see the list of [CUDA-enabled GPU cards](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus). For
> more details on hardware requirements you can refer
> [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#hardware_requirements).

(Paraphrased from  Stanley Zheng and  Dr.Snoopy)